# Connecting to POP3 with gmail fails

Tags: email, outlook, smtp, pop3

when I connect to a POP3 account using Gmail,
It shows POP3 Access Fails for that label

Here I attach a screenshot of the problem.

Error: Server is temporarily unavailable.
Server returned error "Error in RETR command: no such message"

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I suggest you to try with a different email client,
I had similar problem with gmail, but i was able to solved that using sparrow in mac.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue today. I connected to the mail server with Thunderbird. Then, I  deleted spam, deleted mysterious folders named `.ERROR`, removed everything in the trash folder, and compacted all folders. This allowed gmail to download my email again and fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

That´s Yahoo making our lives a little harder. I was able to use during a few months now the Yahoo account from Gmail. But today I started seeing that same error. There´s nothing you can do about it. Yahoo is blocking the Mail Fetcher. Here´s a discussion on that matter --> https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/oUnb3ASPc0g

Answer (score 0):

You need to skip the corrupt mail:

> Set fetch mail of last 30 days (90 days...) on POP setting of your POP3 account email

After that my gmail fetched successfully.