# Facing Connection refused errors for gmail pop3 email reading in java

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am trying to implement email reading in java for gmail. I am mostly concerned with `pop3` and `smtp` connections. I have successfully implemented the functionality for `smtp` but I am facing continuous connection refused errors when using `pop3`. Below is the minimal example.

```
public class ReadEmailStep {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // for smtp
        // String host = "smtp.gmail.com";// change accordingly
        // String mailStoreType = "imaps";

        // for pop3
        String host = "pop.gmail.com";
        String mailStoreType = "pop3s";

        String username = "<email_address>";// change accordingly
        String password = "<password>";// change accordingly
        String folder = "INBOX";
        readMessages(host, mailStoreType, username, password, folder);

    }

    private static void addPop3Props(Properties properties, String host, String port) {
        properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.host", host);
        properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.port", port);
        properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port", port);
        properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.rsetbeforequit", "true");
    }

    private static void addSmtpProps(Properties properties, String host, String port) {
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", port);
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", port);
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    }

    public static void readMessages(String host, String storeType, String user, String password, String folder) {
        try {

            // create properties field
            Properties properties = new Properties();

            if (storeType.equals("pop3s")) {
                addPop3Props(properties, host, "995");
            } else if (storeType.equals("imaps")){
                addSmtpProps(properties, host, "465");
            } else {
                throw new Exception("unknown storeType: " + storeType);
            }

            URLName url = new URLName(storeType, host, 995, "",  user, password);
            Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, null);
            Store store = new POP3SSLStore(session, url);
            store.connect();

           //Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);
           //Store store = emailSession.getStore(storeType);

            store.connect(host, user, password);

            // create the folder object and open it
            Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder(folder);
            emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

            // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it
            Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
            System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);

            //  do something with messages

            // close the store and folder objects
            emailFolder.close(false);
            store.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Following is the stacktrace I am getting;

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Connect failed;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:120)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:233)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:134)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:86)
    at com.smartstream.control.engine.custom.ReadEmailStep.readMessages(ReadEmailStep.java:71)
    at com.smartstream.control.engine.custom.ReadEmailStep.main(ReadEmailStep.java:32)
```

I have already referred to following threads but none of them has helped.

- [Connecting to POP3 with gmail fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18468085/connecting-to-pop3-with-gmail-fails)
- https://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips-100035/61-javamail/2450-connecting-gmail-using-pop3-connection-with-ssl.html

Thanks.

Comment: What is the value of `port`?

Comment: 995 for pop3 and 465 for smtp.

Comment: Is it possible the connection is blocked by a firewall?

Comment: smtp and imap works without any issues so I doubt that is the case. Same issue with yahoo mailbox too. pop3 throws connection refused error.

Comment: Have you read the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug)?  Most likely you have a firewall or anti-virus program that's blocking your use of the pop3 port.